# Is Node.js capable of transferring huge files?

Tags: node.js

We have an API built on top of Node.js which acts as a middleware between two systems A and B. System A will access the data present in system B through middleware. Being a service provider and middleware, we should be in a position to transfer the file from backend and expose the same.

The file size in system B is approximately 1.5 GB and will be transferred as a Base64 string. Currently it is taking more than one minute (approx.) to transfer the file from system B to A.

**Question:**
Is there anyway we can reduce the response time and increase the performance at Node.js end?

Comment: its very hard to tell without seeing your code. Do you use streams to transfer the file?

Comment: Why do you transfer as a base64 string?

Comment: transfer it as a stream or binary - would be faster than encoding/decoding with base64

Comment: @apokryfos System B converts the file into a base64 string and will be decoded at system A.

Comment: Base64 data is 25% larger than the equivalent binary data. If you can avoid encoding and decoding then you should.

Comment: Will try the binary method and get back to you